# Controlling CSS3 column-breaks

Tags: css, less, multiple-columns

I am trying to control column breaks with CSS3 and having some issues with layout.

I'm using less preprocessor to compile the CSS.

My less code creates a class called "details" which is applied to a div.

```
.details {
    .column-count;
    .column-gap(50px);
    .column-rule(1px dotted @bodybackground);
    h3 {
        -webkit-column-span: all;
        -moz-column-span: all;
        column-span: all;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
    }
    h4 {
        &.breakbefore {
            -webkit-break-before: always;
            -moz-break-before: always;
            break-before: always;
        }
        &.breakafter {
            -webkit-break-after: always;
            -moz-break-after: always;
            break-after: always;
        }
    }
    ol li, ul li, table {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

However, the column breaks don't seem to work.

Comment: your demo link doesn't work any more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn):

> Partial support refers to not supporting the break-before, break-after, break-inside properties. Webkit browsers do have equivalent support for the non-standard -webkit-column-break-* properties.

IE10 and Opera 12 (just hope they'll provide their code to WebKit when they'll switch to their new rendering engine...) may have better support (I didn't test it).

Financial Times Labs have released **[columnflow](http://labs.ft.com/articles/ft-columnflow/)**, a very advanced script (maybe too advanced for your use?):

- Configurable column widths, gutters and margins
- Fixed position elements
- Elements spanning columns
- Keep-with-next class to avoid headings at the bottom of a column
- No-wrap class to avoid breaking marked elements across columns
- Grouping of columns into pages
- Standardised line height to align text baseline to a grid
- Rapid reflow on font size change

Or maybe **[columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/)** could help you

Comment: the columnflow is too complex for this site, yes, but it may work well for another site I am working on. However, I'm a bit confused by its usage. Here is the link to the site. http://bit.ly/Ya5LuC Do you think you can help me?

Comment: Did you get my comment to your answer?

Comment: I have posted a qiestion about the use of FTColumnFlow here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587520/implementing-ftcolumnflow-js-in-joomla-3-0